# How do I handle async requests in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures

I make a web service call in one of my functions. I'm having trouble how to structure it so the logic is clean and not redundant. Here's what I have:

```
public func getTimes() -> [TimeName: MyResult] {
    let deferredTask: () -> [TimeName: MyResult] = {
        var computed = self.computeTimes()
        // Do something
        return computed
    }

    // Calculate timezone
    if let tz = timezone {
        timeZone = tz
        return deferredTask()
    } else {
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!) {
            (data, response, error) in

            // Do something with data

            return deferredTask() // Getting a compiler error here btw: is not convertible to 'Void'
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Then I call this using `MyInstance.getTimes()`. Something doesn't feel right though.. is setting up a `deferredTask` variable a good way to avoid redundant code?

Also, when I call this from another function, I would use `var test = MyInstance.getTimes()`. But this means `test` is in an async state and I can't use it in my other function until the web service is finished in `getTimes`.

What's a good way to handle this in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you rightly say, you cannot do this:

```
public func getTimes() -> [TimeName: MyResult] {
    let deferredTask: () -> [TimeName: MyResult] = {
        var computed = self.computeTimes()
        // Do something
        return computed
    }
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!) {
            (data, response, error) in
            // Do something with data
            return deferredTask()
     }.resume()
}
```

The problem, as I think you are correctly trying to say, is that `return deferredTask()` is returned from the surrounding closure - not from `getTimes`. You cannot asynchronously return a value from a function call! That is the nature of asynchrony.

A typical standard solution is to write `getTimes` itself to accept a callback function as its parameter. It itself returns nothing. When the asynchronous method is finished, *it calls the callback*, thus getting the info back, at some future time, to the original caller.

To show you what I mean, I'm going to remove your `deferredTask` entirely from the story and just concentrate on the asynchronous task and the callback. So we would have this:

```
public func getTimes(f:(Any) -> Void) -> () {
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!) {
            (data, response, error) in
            // ...
            f(whatever)
     }.resume()
}
```

The point of this architecture is that the call to `f(whatever)` effectively goes back to whoever handed us `f` in the first place - especially if that entity put `self` into it somewhere.